# Rest template ResponseEntity body is changing the types of variables, how to control the types?

Tags: java, rest, http, spring-restcontroller

I'm making a Post request from an app where i have the below

```
Set<Accounts> set = populateAccounts();
ResponseEntity<Map> responseMap = 
restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/maptest", set, Map.class);
return responseMap.getBody();
```

And this request then returns a Map from responseMap.getBody();

And the below is the code where i receive the post request

```
@PostMapping("/maptest")
public ResponseEntity<Map> mapReturn(@RequestBody Set<Accounts> accounts) {
    HashMap<String, Amount> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("account1", new Amount(BigDecimal.TEN));
    map.put("account2", new Amount(BigDecimal.ZERO));
    return ResponseEntity.ok(map);
}
```

Problem is, the Map that is returned does not have amounts as BigDecimal values, and these BigDecimal values are being automatically converted to an Integer when i see them in responseMap.getbody();

Please help me understand how i can maintain them as BigDecimal values.

Also, the actual code is slightly more elaborate than the above, but i wanted to keep it simple. I absolutely want to keep the values as BigDecimal, just not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using Jackson as the marchalling library for RestTemplate.

When you read the values the `ObjectMapper` reads numbers as ints/doubles etc.
You can easily set the behavior for deserialization using following configuration properties.

[jackson-databind DeserializationFeature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS)

> **USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS**
>
> Feature that determines whether JSON floating point numbers are to be deserialized into BigDecimals if only generic type description (either Object or Number, or within untyped Map or Collection context) is available.
>
> **USE_BIG_INTEGER_FOR_INTS**
>
> Feature that determines whether JSON integral (non-floating-point) numbers are to be deserialized into BigIntegers if only generic type description (either Object or Number, or within untyped Map or Collection context) is available.

To set it you can write as described [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features)

```
ObjectReader r = objectMapper.reader(MyType.class);
// enable one feature, disable another
MyType value = r
  .with(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS)
  .without(DeserializationFeature.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS)
  .readValue(source);
```

or just

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);

OptionTransaction transaction = mapper.readValue(jsonString, OptionTransaction.class);
```

You can of course write your own [number deserializers](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) and use `@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomNumberDeserializer.class)` annotation.

Similar technique is possible in other marchalling libraries (like Gson)

Comment: thank you, you're right im using Jackson databind. What i dont understand is where does this fit in the code i have. Does the OptionTransaction part fit in the code where i have postForEntity? if so, im slightly confused as i get a Map from the response, not a json, so the part 
OptionTransaction transaction = mapper.readValue(jsonString, OptionTransaction.class);
is unclear to me because i see you have jsonString there

Comment: ObjectMapper can convertValues - from one object to the other with different classes. So you can always [convertValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference)).

Comment: You can also configure restTemplate using `restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, createMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());` the parameter is of type `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`